# Pointer is undefined

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

I'm trying to learn C++ out of a book. One of the examples is:

```
string s("some string");
if (s.begin() != s.end())
    auto it = s.begin();
*it == toupper(*it);
```

When I put this into Visual Studio, I receive an error declaring that `*it` is undefined and it won't compile.

I know this is probably the most basic thing of all time, I'm just trying to understand why it's undefined. Is this just a bad example for a pointer to an iterator?

Comment: if you declare a variable in a if block, that variable is out of scope after it exits the if block. It won't exist anymore.

Comment: Look at the indentation of the code snippet. In which scope is the variable `it` defined? In which scope do you attempt to use `it`?

Comment: because ```it``` is defined in ```if``` block scope so it will not be accessible  outside of ```if``` scope

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude indentation does not define scope. Curly braces do.

Comment: I can see four possibilities: 1) That's a terrible book and you should get a better one; 2) There is a serious typo in the book; 3) You didn't copy the example verbatim but "adjusted" it; 4) The example actually illustrates this issue, but you didn't care about reading the explaining text.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, but in this case it do show the correct scope.

Answer (score 4):

`it` is declared as a *local variable* inside of the `if` block. It goes [out of scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) once the `if` block exits. So, in your example, `it` doesn't exist anymore in the `toupper()` operation.

Even if it did exist, the code would be dereferencing the `end` iterator if the string were empty (`begin` and `end` were the same), which is **undefined behavior**.

You need to add curly braces to the `if` block so you can then move the `toupper()` operation inside the block, where `it` is still in scope.

Also, `==` is a *comparison* operator. If the goal is it modify the string, you need to use the `=` *assignment* operator instead.

Try this:

```
string s("some string");
if (s.begin() != s.end()) {
    auto it = s.begin();
    *it = toupper(*it);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You just taught me so much with such a concise reply. Also Gambit is great.